# &#32; on page source

Tags: html, asp.net, encoding

When I display page source from browser, I see page source like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;&#32;charset=ISO-8859-9" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;&#32;charset=windows-1254" />
<title></title>
```

But it is actually like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254" />
    <title></title>
```

Any idea why space characters are converted to `&#32;` ? It happens in all attributes in page source, so I don't want to use htmldecode() as it will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

32 is the ASCII for space.
You can use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` to get the space

Comment: But it is already written directly, not a dynamic string so why is it converted to ASCII?

Comment: As long as it's in an attribute value (or in a text node), there is no problem whatsoever with characters looking like that. How did you write it? What editor did you use?

Comment: I'm using that too, and I never saw it change a space like that. Odd. By the way, off topic but why are you using two different content-type metas?